# tar compare or diff command line

Tags: tar

What is wrong with this?

```
tar --diff --gunzip --file=/media/disk/filename.tgz
```

This is GNU tar 1.23 on Ubuntu.  The complaint is `gzip:stdin:input/output error`.

The following just hangs and there is no apparent disk seek activity.

```
tar --diff fz /media/disk/filename.tgz
tar --compare fz /media/disk/filename.tgz
tar -d vfz /media/disk/filename.tgz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tar --compare --verbose -z --file=filename.tgz ./directory > logfile
```

This or some variant worked.  The point of redirecting to the logfile is to reduce clutter: the 'file not found' sort of differences stay on the console, the rest go into the logfile.  I do not know why the other attempts by the OP did not work.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be `--gzip` or `-z`, but not gunzip.

Also, in your second code block. If you give the `f` argument, there *has to* follow the file:

```
tar --diff zf /media/disk/filename.tgz
tar --compare zf /media/disk/filename.tgz
tar -d vzf /media/disk/filename.tgz
```

All of them work. Notice that I moved the f argument right before the filename.