# Compare folder with tarball

Tags: linux, tar

I have a directory structure like this

```
Code
├── cse701.tgz
└── cse701
    ├── cse701.md
    ├── CSE701.md
    ├── CSE701_pandoc.md
    ├── cse701.pdf
    ├── cse.pdf
    ├── default.yaml
    ├── html2tex.log
    ├── test.md
    └── missing.md
```

And the tarball has a structure like:

```
drwxrwxr-x zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 20:18 cse701/
-rw-rw-r-- zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 21:19 cse701/default.yaml
-rw-rw-r-- zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 21:19 cse701/CSE701.md
-rw-rw-r-- zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 21:19 cse701/CSE701_pandoc.md
-rw-rw-r-- zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 21:19 cse701/html2tex.log
-rw-rw-r-- zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 21:19 cse701/test.md
-rw-rw-r-- zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 21:19 cse701/cse701.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 21:19 cse701/cse.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- zenith/zenith     0 2020-12-02 21:19 cse701/cse701.md
```

```
tar --diff -zf cse701.tgz  cse701/
tar --compare -zf cse701.tgz  ./cse701/
```

The diff and compare options as shown in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/366039/tar-compare-or-diff-command-line/654266#654266) should point out that there is a file missing form the disk that is not on the tarball.

However, the [gnu tar docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/compare.html) says that it will show if the files have been modified, but will ignore files in the file system that
do not have corresponding members in the archive. If a file is represented in the archive but does not exist in the file system, tar reports a difference.

So how do I find if any new files are added to the folder after I created the tarball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a one-liner, but it does what you want:

```
cd /path/to/Code
tar -tf cse701.tgz | sed 's#/$##' >tgz
find cse701 >fs
diff -uw fs tgz
rm fs
rm tgz
```

Explanation:

- First we change to the relevant directory
- Then we list the tar.gz content, removing `/`es at the end of the line (`tar -t` puts them there for directories)
- Then we find all files and directories in the corresponding file system subtree (`find` puts **no** `/`es at the end)
- We diff those two lists
- and clean up

Comment: So I have to list the files in both the directory and the tarball and then compare. It works, but I was kinda hoping I could do this with `tar --diff` or `tar --compare` somehow. But I learned how to use `sed` so thanks are in order.

Comment: The functionality you need is not needed from `tar`'s POV, as tar -u does it fine.